# LibGDX Mouse Event Detection

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to detect and handle any and all mouse press/release events whenever they occur in my HTML5-deployed LibGDX game. I'm struggling with InputAdapter's implementation of touchDown and touchUp, using this as a catch-all for detecting and handling all mouse press/release events.

It seems that if I have one mouse button pressed down (ex: left click) and subsequently press and release another mouse button (ex: right click), by doing this, the intial left click will not be detected by the touchUp when the user is no longer pressing down left click for this sequence of events. Basically whenever a touchUp or touchDown is called, the history of other previous mouse events vanish and remain "unhandled".

I'd like to hope that for each mouse press (touchDown() event) there would always be a subsequent mouse release (touchUp() event) at some point in the future (assuming the user doesn't hold their mouse down essentially "forever" without releasing it).

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            Engine.console("down: " + pointer + " " + button);
            return super.touchDown(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            Engine.console("up: " + pointer + " " + button);
            return super.touchUp(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
        }
    });
```

**My Expected Behavior:**

```
(I physically press left click down)

[LOG] down: 0 0

(I physically press right click down)

[LOG] down: 0 1

(I physically release left click)

[LOG] up: 0 0

(I physically release right click)

[LOG] up: 0 1
```

**Actual Result:**

```
(I physically press left click down)

[LOG] down: 0 0

(I physically press right click down)

nothing detected

(I physically release left click)

[LOG] up: 0 0

(I physically release right click)

nothing detected
```

**How can I achieve my expected behavior?**

Comment: Does Desktop version work as expected? Does this happen for all mouse buttons? Also, make sure, that you right mouse button works :).

Comment: Not sure, I haven't set up desktop compiling. And yeah, I've tried 5 buttons on my mouse, nothing. Also I've had people test on multiple computers with the deployment and they experience the same results. I just found something - possibly the stage is consuming these events or causing a conflict? hm. Glad to hear that the expected result is something I should be getting though and I just have something wrong in the code somewhere.

Comment: Well it isn't the Stage because I'm setting the InputAdapter on a new screen and it technically is capturing events. I've reduced the code down to an 'empty' screen with the above InputAdapter and I'm still unable to see the expected behavior. LibGDX version 1.9.7 in browser - can you verify that this feature should be working in my environment?

Comment: I've just tested Desktop, works correctly. I think this is expected behavior for HTML5 too, because there is nothing about it in the documentation. p.s. It's not because of `Stage` because in your sample code, you don't set `Stage` as input processor of your app, so it won't detect any input.

Comment: I've tested html version, same problem. Although there is a bit more complex behavior: if left button is pressed, right button is never detected.  But if the right button is pressed, left button is detected **after** first try, and after that right button touchUp is not detected. Anyway, seems like a bug. You can open an issue here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues

Comment: Fixed in https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/commit/282838179af81eda0feba3859ffc6db018bc7208